# Delete model instance button

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a for loop that lists all the testimony instances in my model. I'd like to have the button in the code below delete the related instance when clicked.

**html**

```
{% block content %}

{% for testimony in testimonies %}
<a href="{% url "main:update_testimony_view" slug=testimony.slug %}">
    <h3>{{testimony.name}}</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</a>
{% endfor %}

****
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
def create_testimony_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateTestimonyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            testimony = form.save(commit=False)
            testimony.save()
            return redirect('main:homepage_view')
    else:
        form = CreateTestimonyForm
    context = {
        "title": "Create - Testimony",
        "form": form,
        "testimonies": Testimony.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/create/create_testimony.html", context=context)


def update_testimony_view(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Testimony, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateTestimonyForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            testimony = form.save(commit=False)
            testimony.save()
            return redirect('main:homepage_view')
    else:
        form = CreateTestimonyForm(instance=instance)
    context = {
        "title": "Update - Testimony",
        "form": form,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/create/create_testimony.html", context=context)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `POST` request to the server which will delete the instance.

Please have a look at `Form` documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add simple form and view to delete testimony.

html,

```
{% for testimony in testimonies %}
<a href="{% url "main:update_testimony_view" slug=testimony.slug %}">
    <h3>{{testimony.name}}</h3>

 <form action="{% url 'main:delete_testimony' testimony.pk %}" method="POST">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
 </form>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

view,

```
def delete_testimony(request, pk):
    deleted = False
    try:
        Testimony.objects.delete(pk=pk)
        deleted = True
    except Testimony.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return JsonResponse({'deleted':deleted})
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting errors, I'm not sure how to get this working. Also can I reuse this delete function for other models? I've updated my post with my views.py functions